# float image in left margin document. PhpWord 0.18, environment php 8.1, Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel-9, phpword, php-8.1

I need to put the signature in the left margin of the word document, as shown in the following image.

[image]

It worked fine in a PHP 7.4 environment, just put style="float: left" on the image element

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/signature.png') }}" width="50%" style="float: left"/>
```

When I update to a php 8.1 environment, it shows me as follows

[image]

please help

this is my code

> PhpwordController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Exception;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html;

class PhpwordController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        $html = view('document');
        Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);
        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $fileName = 'hello.docx';
        try {
            $objWriter->save(storage_path($fileName));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
        return response()->download(storage_path($fileName))->deleteFileAfterSend();
    }
}
```

> document.blade.php

```
<body style="font-family: Arial Narrow,serif; font-size: 14pt; text-align: justify">
<p><b>PHP</b> is a general-purpose scripting language geared toward web development. It was originally created by
    Danish-Canadian programmer Rasmus Lerdorf in 1993. The PHP reference implementation is now produced by The PHP
    Group. PHP originally stood for Personal Home Page, but it now stands for the recursive initialism PHP:
    Hypertext Preprocessor.
</p>
<img src="{{ asset('img/signature.png') }}" width="50%" style="float: left" alt=""/>
<p>PHP code is usually processed on a web server by a PHP interpreter implemented as a module, a daemon or as a Common
    Gateway Interface (CGI) executable. On a web server, the result of the interpreted and executed PHP code – which may
    be any type of data, such as generated HTML or binary image data – would form the whole or part of an HTTP response.
    Various web template systems, web content management systems, and web frameworks exist which can be employed to
    orchestrate or facilitate the generation of that response. Additionally, PHP can be used for many programming tasks
    outside the web context, such as standalone graphical applications and robotic drone control. PHP code can
    also be directly executed from the command line.
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post the minimal code needed to generate this output? See; [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I already provided the necessary code to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. The result in the php 8.1 environment is what I would expect, so it's the php 7.4 environment that is weird because the signature float left outside the `<div>` container. I would treat this as a normal styling problem. You could try to add styling to push the image into the margin again. For instance: `style="float: left; margin-left: -50pt;"`, or something to the same effect.

Comment: try all forms by putting a negative number, it ignores it